# Jquery - How to select an html element within a div, which is contained in an ASP.NET repeater ItemTemplate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, repeater

I have an ASP.NET repeater, which contains 3 divs inside the ItemTemplate.

Each div, in turn has a number of html elements. I would like to reference an element in the first div (the 3 divs are placed vertically and parallel to each other from left to right).

I have a button in the 3rd div. When pressed, I want to be able to select an element which is contained within the first div.

This is the code I've got so far:

```
$("#editButton").click(function () {
     var nameBox = $(".nameBox", $(this).parent());
            });
```

I'm not really sure how to select the element within the first div though. Could anyone kindly suggest some code please?

Comment: Can you show the HTML that gets rendered in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the siblings and find the element with the class name.

Assuming your markup is like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="namebox">found me</div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="click"/>
</div>


$("#editButton").click(function () {
     var nameBox = $(this).parent().siblings(':eq(0)').find('.nameBox');
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/nQmWm/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What does :eq(0) do?

Comment: I've managed to make it work, but it does not work for each repeater instance for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: `:eq(0)` is a selector getting the first instance of the result. so in this case the first sibling. As for the repeater, is the `ID` unique for each button? If not maybe consider using a class name for the button in the repeater. Example: `$('.myEditButtonClass').click(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you assign an id to the div? Or use the first selector http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/